# Javascript IF/ELSE - Shorten function

Tags: javascript

I am playing around with the JavaScript IF/ELSE to understand better how it works. As an exercise I took the following working hours of a shop:

- 6AM to 6PM = Open
- 6PM to 6AM = Closed

then I created a function that returns the word 'Open' or 'Closed' based on the 2 values "time" and "period".

```js
function shopHours(time,period) {
if (time === 6 && period === 'AM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 6 && period === 'AM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 7 && period === 'AM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 8 && period === 'AM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 9 && period === 'AM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 10 && period === 'AM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 11 && period === 'AM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 12 && period === 'PM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 1 && period === 'PM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 2 && period === 'PM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 3 && period === 'PM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 4 && period === 'PM') {
return 'Open';
} else if (time === 5 && period === 'PM') {
return 'Open';
} else {
return 'Closed';} 
}
```

Everything works fine. However, I would like to be able to shorten the code as it looks too confusing.

I then tried the following:

```js
function shopHours(time,period) {
if(time <= 6 && period === 'AM') {
return 'Closed';
} else if (time >= 6 && period === 'PM') {
return 'Closed';
} else if (time === 12 && period === 'PM') {
return 'Open';
} else {
return 'Open';}
}
```

The second code works fine too and is much shorter however there is a problem that I am not sure how to solve. When the time and period are set to 12 and PM, the result should be 'closed' but I am not sure how to implement this.

I have tried to add the following code but it seems that would not solve this problem.

```
 else if (time === 12 && period === 'AM') {
return 'Closed';
}
```

I will be very grateful to anyone that will spend a bit of his time to take a look at this question.

Thank you!

Comment: Btw, when returning inside an if block, the `else` keyword is not needed. You can just use `if`

Comment: Convert to standard 24h format, then do your comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can break it down into two initial scenarios, either AM or PM. Then check the hour to see if it should be open or closed.

```
if (period == "AM") {
    if (time < 6 || time == 12) 
        return "Closed";
    return "Open";
}
else {
    if (time >= 6 && time != 12)
        return "Closed";
    return "Open";
}
```

Comment: That's also incorrect, isn't it? 12PM should be open.

Comment: thanks for catching that, should be fixed

Comment: Wow, thanks! This works perfectly however I would like to make sure that I fully understand this. I can see that the value is being returned twice as closed and open for both IF and ELSE, would you mind explaining why? Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing - checking AM vs PM alone doesn't give us enough to verify Closed or Open, since those can both happen during AM and PM hours, so both are possible to be returned for a given AM hour or a given PM hour. Does that help clear it up?

Comment: Ah I may have misunderstood your question - nothing is being returned twice. As soon as the function hits a return line, it will return and nothing after the return line will be run in javascript. So that just lets us omit the `else` around `return "Open"`

Comment: Hi! So the way this works is that if for the first IF statement, if the result if true will return ''Closed'' and in case it is false will return ''Open''?

Comment: Yep exactly that. So for the AM block, we check if it's before 6am or if it's 12am. For either, we want it to show closed. Otherwise, the store is open in the AM

Comment: Perfect! Everything is clear now! Thanks a lot for helping with this, is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to work with 24-hour format, in my opinion.
One has to take `12PM = 12:00` and `12AM = 00:00` into account however.

After conversion the comparision is fairly easy.

```js
function shopHours(time, period) {
    let hour = time;
    if (period === 'PM' && hour < 12) hour = hour + 12;
    if (period === 'AM' && hour === 12) hour = hour - 12;

    if (hour >= 6 && hour < 18) {
        return 'Open';
    }

    return 'Closed';
}

console.log('12 AM is ' + shopHours(12, 'AM') + '. Expected it to be: Closed');
console.log('3 AM is ' + shopHours(3, 'AM') + '. Expected it to be: Closed');
console.log('6 AM is ' + shopHours(6, 'AM') + '. Expected it to be: Open');
console.log('9 AM is ' + shopHours(9, 'AM') + '. Expected it to be: Open');
console.log('12 PM is ' + shopHours(12, 'PM') + '. Expected it to be: Open');
console.log('3 PM is ' + shopHours(3, 'PM') + '. Expected it to be: Open');
console.log('6 PM is ' + shopHours(6, 'PM') + '. Expected it to be: Closed');
console.log('9 PM is ' + shopHours(9, 'PM') + '. Expected it to be: Closed');
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for helping with this! The plan was to try this function with both 12 and 24 hour format to see what the difference is but I got stuck with the 12 hour one :D Indeed using the 24 hour format looks more easier than working with the 12 one.

Answer (score 2):

My version.if goal is to just shorten the code, then those `am() and pm()` functions can be omitted and the code inside can be added where am calling them. That would be 3 lines of code.

```js
function shopHours(time, period){
var result;
function am () {
  Number(time) < 12 && Number(time) >= 6 ? result = "open" : result = "closed";
}
function pm() {
    Number(time) <= 5 || Number(time) === 12 ? result = "open" : result = "closed";
}
period === 'AM' ? am() : pm();

return result;
}

console.log("12 AM is: ", shopHours(12, 'AM'), '; expected: closed');
console.log("3 AM is: ", shopHours(3, 'AM'), '; expected: closed');
console.log("6 AM is: ", shopHours(6, 'AM'), '; expected: open');
console.log("9 AM is: ", shopHours(9, 'AM'), '; expected: open');
console.log("12 PM is: ", shopHours(12, 'PM'), '; expected: open');
console.log("3 PM is: ", shopHours(3, 'PM'), '; expected: open');
console.log("6 PM is: ", shopHours(6, 'PM'), '; expected: closed');
console.log("9 PM is: ", shopHours(9, 'PM'), '; expected: closed');
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily handled using date instead. Instead of using if else, You can define the `openHours` and `closeHours`. And pass the current time. You can easily compare then.

**Sample:**

```js
function shopHours(time, period) {
  let openHour = new Date();
  let closeHour = new Date();
  openHour.setHours(6);
  closeHour.setHours(12 + 6);

  let curreTime = new Date();
  curreTime.setHours(period === "PM" ? 12 + time : time);
  if (curreTime > openHour && curreTime < closeHour) return "Open";
  return "Close";
}

console.log(shopHours(11, "PM"));
console.log(shopHours(12, "AM"));
console.log(shopHours(11, "AM"));
console.log(shopHours(7, "AM"));
console.log(shopHours(5, "AM"));
```

You can also just pass the currentTime and validate.

```js
function shopHours(curreTime) {
  let openHour = new Date();
  let closeHour = new Date();
  openHour.setHours(6);
  closeHour.setHours(12 + 6);
  if (curreTime > openHour && curreTime < closeHour) return "Open";
  return "Close";
}

console.log(shopHours(new Date()));
```

Comment: I think your example contains a mistake. `curreTime.setHours(period === "PM" ? 12 + time : time);` results in 12PM being 00:00 / 24:00 and 12AM being 12:00, as far as I can tell. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```js
function shopHours(time, period) {
  var status = "Open";
  if ((period == "AM" && (time < 6 || time == 12)) || (time >= 6 && time != 12)) status = "Closed";
  return status;
}

console.log(shopHours(5, "AM"));
console.log(shopHours(5, "PM"));
```